# How to get the data of a query from firebase database in react-native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to list the data of each document that i am fetching from a firebase query, However I am being able to show the data through flatlist, Iwoudl love to iterate the data in another way in order to add it to a PDF that will be created from the app.

```
const [Annotations, setAnnotations] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(
      collection(db, "notifications"),
      orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
    );
    console.log("Query:");
    console.log(q);
    onSnapshot(q, (test) => {
      setAnnotations(test.docs);
    });

  }, []);
```

From the code above  I am getting some unneccesary data, however I’d like to get the data of the document, hope you help me, thanks!

Comment: from where are you getting unnecessary data? Is it from test.docs??

Comment: thanks for the comment @Haritha Senevirathne, What I mean is that wheen I do the query, I get an object with some empty fields that are not related to the information stored in database, what I dont know is how to access to the object gotten from the query or how to iterate through it

Comment: looks like you are not following the documentation correctly. I suggest you to carefully go through this https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing are the internals of the Firestore `DocumentSnapshot` and `QueryDocumentSnapshot` classes, which is indeed pretty meaningless.

If you only want to use the data:

```
onSnapshot(q, (test) => {
  setAnnotations(test.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
});
```

If you want the data and document ID:

```
onSnapshot(q, (test) => {
  setAnnotations(test.docs.map((doc) => { doc.id, ...doc.data() }));
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  Frank van Pufflen, it worked pretty good!